# How to create a release pipeline on Azure for an Angular project

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I wanted to learn e2e deployment of an Angular project. I've a free trial subscription. I've created an app service already and it is running also. See:
[image]

But on devops when I try to create a release pipeline the dropdown is empty. It says *No subscription or service connection found*. See:
[image]

the subscription is also active:

[image]

This is the screenshot of **Project Settings -> service connections -> New service connection -> Azure resource manager -> Service principal (automatic) -> Next (button):**

[image]

I refreshed multiple times. Deleted the app service and created new service again and again then refreshed again. I was following this YouTube tutorial:
[Deploy Angular app using Azure DevOps build and release pipelines](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LwDYfL7mGfw&ab_channel=AskarMusthaffa)

I've commented for help but the person has not replied yet. I watched this video on repeat mode to see If I missed out an important step. Please help me. I tried tips from Microsoft Azure help/troubleshoot page.

Comment: Did you try add new service connection? The button  `+New` after Azure subscription.

Comment: Have a look at this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops

Comment: Yes I've gone through this document and it didn't help

Comment: Could you post the screenshot of Service connections page? Your Devops Project-->  Project settings--> Service connections

Comment: @DorisLv Added what you asked. Please help.

Comment: Hi @Tanzeel, You need log in [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Billing/SubscriptionsBlade) to check if your subscription status is active. You could refer to this [blog](https://blog.georgekosmidis.net/2020/06/14/troubleshooting-you-dont-appear-to-have-an-active-azure-subscription/) to check it and then kindly share the result here.

Comment: I tried to check free account's subscription status, but I don't have a free account...So you should check it follow the link Vito Liu post.

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT, i have a subscription and i have a service running also. See I've added the screenshot also in the question.

Comment: @DorisLv, See i've added screenshot for the same as vito Liu asked.

Comment: Ok, just follow the troubleshooting blog Vito post, check all the steps.

Comment: @DorisLv, Can we have a google call please? I'll share my screen and will do it together ?

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT, I followed the blog and the last trick worked. this one i mean "Azure Active Directory Security". Please add this as an answer I'll accept the asnwer and close the question.

Comment: Hi @Tanzeel, Glad to hear that your problem has been solved. I have added the answer, you could check it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You don’t appear to have an active Azure subscription.

We need log in [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Billing/SubscriptionsBlade) to check if your subscription status is active. If the subscription status is active, we should search for “Tenant properties” and disable Security defaults. This solves the problem. We could check this [blog](https://blog.georgekosmidis.net/2020/06/14/troubleshooting-you-dont-appear-to-have-an-active-azure-subscription/) for more details.

[image]